# Convert .mp3/.wav file into g729/amr/g711 codec file and vice versa using PJSIP

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, pjsip

**PJSIP** is used for SIP *Registering*, *audio/video Calling* and supporting some other VoIP Call features. If you want to create an VoIP Application, you will create an application using their libraries.

In this library, there are available lot of codecs and some of codecs are available as third party codecs and you can integrate into PJSIP library. Then you can able to support those codecs while calling another SIP user/client.

> Generally In mobile phones, the voice is record as audio file through
>   mic and it has passed to PJSIP library. Then those codec/pjmedia library take care
>   of other operations like converting into anyother codec format which
>   they want to send.

Instead of that, can we able to pass **.mp3/.wav** file into PJSIP library and convert it into codec files like **.g729/.amr/.g711-u** and vice versa

I don't about how codec conversion/codec engine internally works around. 
If you know about the codec conversion from .mp3 format is possible using PJSIP library, please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance!